# Convert to pdf/a-1 under ISO 19005

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking for an API that will enable me to convert `.doc` or `.pdf` files to PDF/A-1. I want this to make my files match with the ISO 19005 norm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert to PDF/A and check compliance under Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/convert-to-pdf-a-and-check-compliance-under-linux)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a (free as in beer, or Free as in Liberty) **API** that allows you to do that in a reliable, easy-to-use and verified way.

Ghostscript as a commandline tool will work, more or less. See these answers:

- "[**How to use Ghostscript DLL to convert PDF to PDF/A**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982233/359307)"
- "[**How to use Ghostscript to convert PDF to PDF/A or PDF/X ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483801/359307)"
- "[**Create print-ready PDF/X (with bleedbox, trimbox, mediabox, etc) programatically?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491668/359307)"

The resulting PDF will claim to be PDF/A-1***b*** (and Adobe Reader will show a hint about this). However, you'll still not have a 100% verification that the PDF is really conforming to the standard's spec.

***If your business relies on a meticulous match, you should at least get some tests with commercial-professional PDF/A validation tools done, before you switch to this method in production.***

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows OS and you can consider commercial libraries, then you can give [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/features.html) a try.

Amyuni PDF Converter is a virtual printer driver that you can control programmatically from your application using either a COM/ActiveX interface, or a .Net assembly; and you can configure it for PDF/A output.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 0):

For PDF files I recommend you to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). It's capable of converting PDF documents to PDF/A-1b ones.

Here is a sample for the task:

```
public static void convertToPdfA(string input, string output)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(input))
    {
        pdf.SaveOptions.ProducePdfA = true;
        pdf.Save(output);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.